# OpenLayers: Mix sorting for layers and features

Tags: openlayers

We use a bunch of different layers from different sources with OpenLayers 6.5. One of these layers is a MVT layer, containing a dozen different features.
I am able to setup an individual style for each of these features and I can sort them within the mvt layer as well:

```
     const style = new Style({
        fill: new Fill({
            color: hexToRGB(layerData.layerColorFill, layerData.layerOpacity),
        }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
            color: hexToRGB(layerData.layerColorStroke, layerData.layerOpacity),
            width: layerData.layerStrokeWidth,
        }),
        zIndex: -layerData.layerOrder,
    });
```

Is it somehow possible to move one of these features out of the MVT layer behind another ZXY layer? It looks like the zIndex property only applies to all features within a layer, but not through the whole map.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two MVT layers sharing the same source.  Here https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-tile-info-forked-g9d08 the country names are seen through the semi opaque XYZ layer while city names are above it, Specify a unique layer `className` otherwise decluttered items will be rendered together above all other layers.